# Mysql query help

Tags: php, mysql

A query is returning me the following structure:

```
24 | 24,879
45 | 657,45
77 | 77,15
```

etc. With php, I can get that to an array, like!

```
$array = (24=>"24,879",45=>"657,45",77=>"77,15");
```

Now what I need, is a second query like:

```
update $table set $col = 24 if $col in (24,879)
```

More precisely, something like:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
mysql_query("update `$table` set `$col` = $k if `$col` in ($v)");
}
```

Tricky, isn't it? Help will be appreciated.

EDIT: The query that returns the comma separated things is below:

```
SELECT n.id, o.email, count( o.email ) AS c, 
CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.id ) AS char ) AS nid 
FROM 0_member AS n JOIN member_base AS o ON o.email = n.login_userid 
GROUP BY o.email HAVING c >1
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? (The answer to "Tricky, isn't it?" is "Yes, it is" :D)

Comment: can you show us the query that is returning that structure?

Comment: So, in table `member_base` there are rows with same `email` but different `id` so you `group by email` to find those and then change their `0_member.id` to the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
UPDATE table SET column = 24 WHERE column IN (24, 879)
```

Comment: No that's not what he needs, apparently he's storing multiple values separated by , as a string in his column. So using IN will not work.

Comment: Well, I got the 24,879 using `CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT old.id ) AS char ) AS newID` in a diferent query, that I mentioned above. Now does that changes anything with NA's reply?

Answer (score 0):

Explode the data contained in `$v` and then run an `if` query before running the mysql data.